# How to set a callback with parameters in cocos2dx?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

Typically you can use `CC_CALLBACK_X` to set a callback for functions where it only accepts the `Ref*` param:

```
//cocos2dx builtins
#define CC_CALLBACK_1(__selector__,__target__, ...) std::bind(&__selector__,__target__, std::placeholders::_1, ##__VA_ARGS__)
typedef std::function<void(Ref*)> ccMenuCallback;
void MenuItem::setCallback(const ccMenuCallback& callback)


//my code starts here   
MyClass::my_callback(Ref* sender) { ... };

MyClass::init()
{
  auto menu = Menu::create();
  auto menuitem = MenuItem::create();
  menuitem->setCallback(CC_CALLBACK_1(MyClass::my_callback, this));
};
```

which works fine.

The problem is say I've got a callback I want to use with another arg, say an `int`, I don't know how to get it working.

```
MyClass::my_callback_with_param(Ref* sender, int arg1) { ... };
MyClass::my_callback_with_param_swapped(int arg1, Ref* sender) { ... };

//in the init func, I've tried stuff like

int an_int = 2
menuitem->setCallback(CC_CALLBACK_2(MyClass::my_callback_with_param, this, an_int));
//or changing the signature of the function
menuitem->setCallback(CC_CALLBACK_2(MyClass::my_callback_with_param_swapped, an_int, this));
//or using std::bind (which I'm not very familiar with)
menuitem->setCallback(CC_CALLBACK_1(std::bind(MyClass::my_callback_with_param, this, std::placeholders::_1) 1);
//or a lambda
menuitem->setCallBack(CC_CALLBACK_1([](Ref* sender){  }, this));
```

What do I need to do to be able to create a callback of a function with parameters already filled in?

Comment: If you use `std::bind` don't use the macros (as you shown in the question the macros themselves use `std::bind`). Example using [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind): `std::bind(&MyClass::my_callback_with_param, this, std::placeholders::_1, an_int)`

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I think that was it. Throw it in an answer. Thanks.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yeah that was definitely it. My issue was that I was using an auto variable during my testing to save on typing out all these temp variables, and the type created by using `CC_CALLBACK_X` wasn't compatible with the lambdas or the binds I was making the whole time. So, close but not cigar. Your answer was just the ticket, thanks again..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
menuitem->setCallback(std::bind(MyClass::my_callback_with_param, this, 1);
```

call `std::bind` on the method name, pass `this` as the first param, and then whatever else you want after.  Works with unlimited variables.